# How to push an array in a for-loop statement, in ActionScript

Tags: arrays, actionscript, for-loop, array-push

I'm sorry if I'm being vague in any way as I'm nooby at AS3.0 and stackoverflow. 
I simply wanna push the `i` variable to add to the variable `_bullets`.

```
var i:int = 0; //initializing the i variable

_bullets.push(i);

//Loops thought all the bullets on stage
for (var i:int = 0; i > _bullets.length; i++)
{
//Some code...
}
```

The result i wanna achieve is that the for-loop now has something to loop through. If more information is needed I will do my best to provide it.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What does `_bullet` contain, and what do you want to do in the loop? Do you want to fill the `_bullet` array in the loop to initialize it, ou is there already something in it that you want to use in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your are trying to do, but there are at least two mistakes in your code:

1. the variable `i` is declared two times: at the fist line, and in the loop.
2. the continuation test in the loop is wrong. It should be

   ```
   for (var i:int = 0; i < _bullets.length; i++)
   ```

`_bullets` is supposed to be an `Array` of `int` ? So `_bullets.push(i)` will add the content of the variable `i` (here `0`) at the end of your array. Is it what you wanted to do ?

Then, if you want to iterate through the elements of `_bullets`, you can use a `for each` loop if you don't care about the value of `i`:

```
for each (var bullet:int in _bullets ) 
{
    // some code using bullet
}
```

it is equivalent to

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < _bullets.length; i++ ) 
{
    var bullet:int = _bullet[i];
    // some code using bullet
}
```